# Plaid Stripe Integration without using Plaid Link

Tags: plaid

I am in the process of integrating Plaid and Stripe, but do not want to use the Plaid Link module to do this.

Once I use the Plaid 'auth' api to authorize a bank account, is there an end-point I can hit to send the information over to Stripe. Note that Plaid's 'exchange-token' end-point does not work as I need a public token to access the end-point.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and opened a support ticket with Plaid. I was told that I need to use Plaid Link.

> Are there endpoints I can use with a user that I have already authd to get the public_token that is normally provided by this module?
>
> No, not currently. These users will need to go through the flow
>   described in our Plaid + Stripe documentation here:
>   https://plaid.com/docs/link/stripe/